# Blocked iframe work-around

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I have the following iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.weddingwire.com/morgancamille" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="weddingwirersvp" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="600px" width="600px"></iframe>
```

... and it would appear that the website who's form I would like to display elsewhere has some iframe-specific parameters to deter people from displaying the form on other sites. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: What error or evidence are you seeing that something is blocked?

Comment: Just an empty <body> tag within the iframe. If I link to another url, the iframe works lovely.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the document to that particular iframe may help. Otherwise, you are running up against the intended purpose of iframes. You say you want to display elsewhere, but the purpose of an iframe is to prevent it from being displayed elsewhere.

[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) May be helpful here.